# VBA - Choosing Destination Folder for Saving File

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm a total VBA noob and need a little help. If it matters I'm using Microsoft Word 2016 on a Mac. I'm using mail merge to create a word doc, and need to split the resulting word doc into multiple pages based on section breaks. I found [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306348) page with VBA code to split the pages and it works great. The only issue I'm having is it's saving to a random place on my computer (I have no idea how it's deciding where to save). Here's the code I'm working with:

```
Sub BreakOnSection()     
   ' Used to set criteria for moving through the document by section.     
   Application.Browser.Target = wdBrowseSection     

   'A mail merge document ends with a section break next page.     
   'Subtracting one from the section count stop error message.     
   For i = 1 To ((ActiveDocument.Sections.Count) - 1)     

'Note: If a document does not end with a section break,     
'substitute the following line of code for the one above:     
'For I = 1 To ActiveDocument.Sections.Count     

      'Select and copy the section text to the clipboard.     
      ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Section").Range.Copy     

      'Create a new document to paste text from clipboard.     
      Documents.Add     
      Selection.Paste     

   ' Removes the break that is copied at the end of the section, if any.     
      Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend     
      Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1     
ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\"     
      DocNum = DocNum + 1     
     ActiveDocument.SaveAs fileName:="test_" & DocNum & ".doc"     
     ActiveDocument.Close     
      ' Move the selection to the next section in the document.     
     Application.Browser.Next     
   Next i     
   ActiveDocument.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges     
End Sub
```

I see the ChangeFileOpenDirectory is set to "C:\" which isn't right for a mac, but what would I need to change to have it ask me where to save all the resulting docs? I don't want to select a folder for each individual doc, but rather select one folder for all of the docs to save into and let it run.
Thanks in advance for the help, I've tried a few hours of google and am still unsure on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this on a mac but it should be

```
Dim mySaveLocation As String
Dim dlg As FileDialog

Set dlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
dlg.AllowMultiSelect = False
dlg.Show
mySaveLocation = dlg.SelectedItems.Item(1)
```

and then when you save it

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs fileName:= mySaveLocation  & "\test_" & DocNum & ".doc"
```